# Ajax script to store user info to the DB in Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, view

**Overview:**

In my django project that displays posts in a News feeds page, I'd like users to be able to “pick” posts (i.e. pin in Pinterest). The idea is to create a “Pick” button that stores automatically information in the Pick table (model defined below) .

```
class Post(models.Model):
    picks=models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Pick',related_name='UserPicks')
    …

class User (models.Model):
    …
```

and

```
class Pick(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User)
    post=models.ForeignKey(Post)
    pick_date = models.DateTimeField('date picked',default=datetime.datetime.now())
```

**Problem**

The problem is to send information automatically and directly to the backend by pressing the button pick without asking the user to fill any form.

**Question**

I'd like to use Ajax in the News feeds HTML page in order to send  the user.id, post.id and date picked to the Pick table of the DB when the user picks the post (by pressing the pick button).

Could you guide me to the appropriate Ajax function and corresponding django view to store this information ?

Comment: It's not clear what your question is here. This is pretty basic stuff, and should be simple once you've done some Django and jQuery tutorials. Where exactly are you having difficulties?

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Yes it is basic Jquerry, I know how to label a button that once pressed would load a new page, show the form asking for this pick information and store it in the DB once submitted (like in the admin page if you try to enter a row to my Pick table). But I have difficulties sending this information directly to the DB without reloading the page (I.e send the user_id of the user authenticated, the post_id he is picking and the date and time).

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that `{{Post.id}}` returns the id of the post, our button is:

```
<a class="click" data-id="{{ Post.id }}" class="btn btn-mini btn-primary" type="button">Pick</a>
```

the jQuery code is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.click').click(function (){
  console.log("create post is working!")
  var pickid;
  pickid = $(this).attr("data-id");
    $.post("create_date/", {pickid: pickid}, function(data){
        alert('Button click recorded.')
    });    
})
  });
```

and a possible view:

```
def record_button_click(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        pick_id = request.POST.get('pickid')
        response_data = {}
        form=Pick(post_id=pick_id,user=request.user)
        form.save()

        response_data['result'] = 'Create post successful!'

        return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps(response_data),
            content_type="application/json"
        )
    else:
        return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps({"nothing to see": "this isn't happening"}),
            content_type="application/json"
        )
```